# Deployment from Visual Studio is stuck at "Installation is in progress"

Tags: visual-studio, deploy

When deploying a SharePoint App, the deployment is stuck. Visual Studio build output shows:

> Install app for SharePoint:
>   Uploading the app for SharePoint...
>   Installation is in progress (00:00:00)
>   Installation is in progress (00:00:01)
>   Installation is in progress (00:00:02)
>   Installation is in progress (00:00:03)
>   Installation is in progress (00:00:04)
>   Installation is in progress (00:00:05)
>   [...]

and a new message “Installation is in progress” is appended once per second, forever, as if the deployment was stuck in an infinite loop. I waited for fifteen minutes; the situation haven't changed.

There is no errors in the logs, neither on development machine, nor on the server hosting SharePoint.

What should I do to make the deployment work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was found on [MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/4ab37d3b-9def-4097-ade6-fa0e3945b099/installing-sharepoint-2013-application-does-not-finish):

Run `services.msc` and **start the following services:**

- SharePoint Administration
- SharePoint Timer Service

Then, in IIS Manager, **restart SharePoint applications.**

If the startup type is set to *Manual*, change it to *Automatic* to avoid the error in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem on SharePoint Server 2013 SP1(​15.0.4797.1000) and VS 2015. Services and accounts were Ok.

**It's a bug**. Installing October CU(15.0.4867.1000) helped

See list of cumulative updates in Todd Klindt's blog:
http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346